How to trigger recomposition when observing LiveData
I'm migrating an app from views to compose and am trying to trigger a schedule update every five minutes in which if there is a change in the data compose should recompose.  Still using RxJava in my vm, but I see getDataList() get called every 5 minutes, but I'm unsure how to update the list when dealing with state.
Here's my code so far:
In compose

val dataList by viewModel.data.observeAsState()

    LaunchedEffect(Unit) {
        while(true) {
            viewModel.getDataList()
            delay(5 * 60 * 1000)
        }
    }

In viewmodel
private val _data = MutableLiveData<List<Item>>()
    val data: LiveData<List<Item>> = _data

    fun getDataList() {
        compositeDisposable.add(repository
            .getData()
            .subscribe(
                { data ->
                    _data.postValue(data)
                },
                {
                    it.printStackTrace()
                }))
    }


You should probably switch out the LiveData with a flow: https://kotlinlang.org/api/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-rx2/

LazyColumn and derivatives are pretty straightforward:
    val dataList by viewModel.data.observeAsState(emptyList())

    LazyColumn {
        items(dataList, key = { item -> item.id }) { data ->
            Text("Something $data")
        }
    }

key is optional, but it's a good optimization to reduce number of recompositions. Inside the itemContent @Composable closure you define how each item should be rendered - in my case a simple Text

Thanks, but I'm looking for a way to trigger the data to be fetched and my composables to be recomposed every 5 minutes.
